# grouping variables of different type Java Requirement

Tags: java

Scenario is like this :

```
class Graph{
    // Now many variables

    Node masterUser;
    Node masterFilter;
    Node masterLocation;

    Index indexUser;
    Index indexFilter;

    Graph() {
        // INITIALIZE ALL Variables Here
    }
}


// SubClass

class MyClass{

    Graph graph = new Graph();

    // NOW I Can refer all class members of Graph class here by graph Object

}
```

What is happening now is when I do `graph.` all members will be accessible.

But I want to group variables of class Graph such that

When user do `graph.Index.` Then only all `Index` will be accessible.
When user do `graph.Nodes.` Then only all `Node`s will be accessible.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you writing a java editor?

Comment: The code above is NOT java code - please correct it or remove the "java" tag!

Comment: @mschenk74 : Ohh yes , I am changing Class name from 'get Graph' to 'Graph' . Hopefully then you can understand it is JAVA Code..

Comment: @mschenk74: Hi I change code and you can see it is java code .. Its really weird people mind these things even when they have right to edit the code to make  it correct but instead of this they like to give comments instead of answers

Comment: Is this about variable name auto complete? Some IDEs will do that

Comment: @RichardTingle : Thanks , I got answer below . :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what interfaces are for.

```
interface GraphNodes {        
    public Node getMasterUser();
    public Node getMasterFilter();
    public Node getMasterLocation();
}

interface GraphIndexes {
    public Index getIndexUser();
    public Index getIndexFilter();
}

class Graph implements GraphNodes, GraphIndexes {
    private Node masterUser;
    private Node masterFilter;
    private Node masterLocation;
    private Index indexUser;
    private Index indexFilter;

    public GraphNodes getNode() { return this; }
    public GraphIndexes getIndex() { return this; }

    public Node getMasterUser() { return this->masterUser; }
    public Node getMasterFilter() { return this->masterFilter; }
    public Node getMasterLocation() { return this->masterLocation; }
    public Index getIndexUser() { return this->indexUser; }
    public Index getIndexFilter() { return this->indexFilter; }
}
```

Now if you have an instance of the `Graph` class, and you write:

```
Graph graph = new Graph();
graph.getIndex()./* ... */
```

you will be able to access only the getter methods for the indexes, and if you type

```
graph.getNode()./* ... */
```

you can access only the nodes.

Comment: Thanks man , I was looking for this. Thanks atleast for not giving 'this is NOT JAVA Code' comment.